# Save position or status of my order using SortableJS

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

good, I am making a system to carry the process of the impressions of clients, for my work and I am trying to use SortableJS to make the change of status, from Revision> Impression> finishes> Finished but I cannot do how to pass the order codes or id the code in jquery, I would appreciate your help

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.2/Sortable.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vysdigitalco.com/styles.css">

<script>

var revision = document.getElementById('revision'),
    impresion = document.getElementById('impresion'),
    terminado = document.getElementById('terminado'),
    finalizado = document.getElementById('finalizado');

var revision_d = Sortable.create(revision, {
    group: 'shared', 
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function () {
        
    },
});

var impresion_d = Sortable.create(impresion, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function () {
        
    },
});

var terminado_d = Sortable.create(terminado, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function (orden) {

    },
});

var finalizado_d = Sortable.create(finalizado, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function (orden) {
        
    },
});

</script>

<section class="content"> 

    <center><h1 class="col-md-12">Proceso de trabajo</h1></center><br>

    <div id="shared-lists" class="row">      

      <div id="revision" class="list-group col">
        <h4 class="col">En revision</h4>
        <div class="list-group-item" id="000001">

        Item 1<br>        
        <small>Vinilo de 200x200 cm | laminado | Ojales</small><br>
        <small>1000 Bolantes 20x15 cm | ambas caras | laminado</small>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="impresion" class="list-group col">
        <h4>Para Impresion</h4>
        <div class="list-group-item" id="000002">

        Item 2<br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="terminado" class="list-group col">
        <h4>Para Terminado</h4>
        <div class="list-group-item" id="000003">

        Item 3<br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small>
      </div>
      </div>

      
      <div id="finalizado" class="list-group col">
        <h4>Trabajo Finalizado</h4> 
        <div class="list-group-item" id="000004">

        Item 4<br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small><br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small><br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small><br>
        <small>#000000 - Lennyn Mendoza</small>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

      <h1 class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</h1>
             
</section>
```

i need help

Comment: Can you more specific on your question ? What are you expecting by ` passing order codes or id to jquery` ?

Comment: I want to pass the orderid from the html to the function to ajax or jquery in order to update the status: if I move the order 0001 from revision to print, the status is changed in the db

Answer (score 1):

On each sortable js initialization add this event handler

```
onEnd: function(evt) {
    //This was the element that you are sorted
    const draggedElement = evt.item;
    // The element of target location
    const toContainer = evt.to;
    // The element of source location;
    const fromContainer = evt.from

    // in your case you added all the data as ID so
    var data = {
        itemID: draggedElement.id,
        targetID: toContainer.id
    };
    $.post(URL, data).then(function(res) {
        //Manage response
    });

},
```

Comment: thanks so muh Flames :D <3 but the $.post action get error

Comment: First you have to include jQuery   and try `jQuery.post`